# PHP - Parse - error":"at least one ID field (installationId,deviceToken) must be specified

Tags: php, curl, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to get a list of installations based on a userID field.  Currently this returns the error "at least one ID field (installationId,deviceToken) must be specified in this operation"

```
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/installations';
$user_id = "3014";
$APPLICATION_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$REST_API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$MASTER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$data = array
    (
        "where" => array(
            "userID" => $user_id,
        ),
    );

$_data = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
    'X-Parse-Master-Key: ' . $MASTER_KEY,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);
curl_close($ch);
```

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing code,or you do not have your $variables assigned properly. Please update your OP with more code.

Comment: Also, are you trying to POST the values into a DB, or echo them on a page, what are you trying to do specifically? I may have a curl snippet I can give you to help you achieve what you're after, but I need more details.

Comment: sorry, yes all the $variables are assigned.

Comment: Currently I'm just trying to echo the results.

Comment: Please post all your code with the assigned variables so I can see how you have things laid out and I will post an answer.

Comment: Added an answer. Assign your vars, and you can add the columns you're trying to request. It will echo a basic layout. Just make sure you accept the answer.@user1092872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a POST request where you should be doing a GET request, see https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-query-constraints

Answer (score 0):

You will want to name your $vars, and only change the 'column' to the column name you're trying to pull. Note it must be identical in spelling/capital chars too.

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    td {
        text-align:center;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    include_once 'DB.Connect.php';

    // error_reporting(E_ALL); 


        $url="http://url.com"

        $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);        

    $DataA = json_decode($json, TRUE);  
    $c = 0;

    echo '<center><table>';
    echo '<tr><th>Title</th></tr>';

    foreach ($DataA as $data) { 

        $var        = $DataA[$c]['column'];         

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$DataA[$c]['column'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>None</td>';
        echo '<td></td>';       
        echo '</tr>';
            }


        $c++;

        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```